# Android studio Sending a post request does not work

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried all the methods, but not how it is not possible to send a post request for a .php file.

```
Fuel.post("https://httpbin.org/post")
    .jsonBody("{ \"foo\" : \"bar\" }")
    .also { println(it) }
    .response { result -> }
```

My test file (test.php)

```
<?
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Result is empty in (test.php)

```
Array()
```

Libraries

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-gson:2.3.1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this actually an [tag:android-studio] question or did you mean [tag:Android]?

Comment: Posting a request to httpbin works fine for me in the way you showed. For the PHP file, where are you hosting it? Make sure the PHP web server is up and working.

Comment: php works fine, via HttpURLConnection sends post request ok, however it is synchronous and this is a problem, I need asynchronous code.Maybe a library with a bug, I'll try another library.